# Using OR in the query builder with eager loading

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

CakePHP Version: 4.1.4

**Introduction**
I'm trying to use the query builder to build complex where clauses and use eager loading.

**SQL**
I'm using 10.4.14-MariaDB as the database server and PHP version 7.4.10 in an xampp environment. The following query returns the desired result set when ran in xampp.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    tasks
JOIN users ON
    users.id = tasks.user_id
WHERE tasks.status = 1
AND tasks.account_id = 1393
AND users.authorised' = 'yes'
OR users.area_id = 1346;
```

---

The information I've referenced for attempt 1 and 2 can be found [here](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions).

**ATTEMPT 1**
I normally use where then andWhere in the query construction so my first attempt was:

```
$query = $Tasks->find()
    ->contain(['Users'])
    ->where([
        'Tasks.status' => 1,
    ])
    ->andWhere([
        'Tasks.account_id' => 1393,
        'Users.authorised' => 'yes',
        'OR' => [['Users.area_id' => 1346]]
    ]);
```

**ATTEMPT 2**

```
$query = $Tasks->find()
    ->contain(['Users'])
    ->where(['Tasks.status' => 1])
    ->where(['Tasks.account_id' => 1393])
    ->where([
        'Users.authorised' => 'yes'
        'OR' => [['Users.area_id' => 1346]]
    ]);
```

---

The information I've referenced for attempt 3 and 4 can be found [here](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#passing-conditions-to-contain).

**ATTEMPT 3**

```
$query = $Tasks->find()->contain('Users', function (Query $q) {
    return $q
        ->where(['Tasks.status' => 1])
        ->andWhere([
            'Tasks.account_id' => 1393,
            'Users.authorised' => 'yes',
            'OR' => [['Users.area_id' => 1346]]
        ]);
});
```

**ATTEMPT 4**

```
$query = $Tasks->find()->contain('Users', function (Query $q) {
    return $q
        ->where(['Tasks.status' => 1])
        ->where(['Tasks.account_id' => 1393])
        ->where([
            'Users.authorised' => 'yes',
            'OR' => [['Users.area_id' => 1346]]
        ]);
});
```

---

**ATTEMPTS SUMMARY**
None of my attempts returned the desired result set. If I remove the OR condition the expected result set is returned.

**QUESTION**
How can I construct the SQL query above which does return the desired result set using the query builder.

Thanks Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of query you want, here are two examples:

```
// WHERE (tasks.status = 1 AND tasks.account_id = 1393 AND users.authorised' = 'yes') OR users.area_id = 1346;

$query = $Tasks->find()
    ->contain(['Users'])
    ->where([
        'OR' => [
            ['Tasks.status' => 1,'Tasks.account_id' => 1393, 'Users.authorised' => 'yes'],
            ['Users.area_id' => 1346],
        ],
    ]);

// WHERE tasks.status = 1 AND tasks.account_id = 1393 AND (users.authorised' = 'yes' OR users.area_id = 1346);

$query = $Tasks->find()
    ->contain(['Users'])
    ->where([
        'Tasks.status' => 1,'Tasks.account_id' => 1393, 
        'OR' => [
            ['Users.authorised' => 'yes'],
            ['Users.area_id' => 1346],
        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: After further testing my SQL query did return a task that was not assigned to the account which was not what I wanted. Your first example returned the same result set as my SQL query. You second example however did not include the task which was not assigned to the account and is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: You should spend some time to understand the difference in the two SQL statements, and how that is reflected in the two different ORM solutions. Otherwise, you have "solved" this problem, but will be no closer to solving the next one.

Comment: @Greg Schmidt - I did a bit. The ORM code - The first example returned a task that was not assigned to the account because the Tasks.account_id' => 1393 is within the OR condition. IE: Select tasks where 'Tasks.status' => 1, OR Tasks.account_id' => 1393. The second example did'nt return the task which was not assigned to the account because it is stipulated outside the OR condition and within the where condition. IE: Select tasks where 'Tasks.status' => 1, and where 'Tasks.account_id' => 1393 then the OR...